# what is the probability that the two tallest boys are in different teams?

Tags: combinatorics

If $22$ boys are randomly divided into two teams;containing $11$ boys each,then what is the probability that the two tallest boys are in different teams?

Probability that the two tallest boys are in different teams=number of ways that 2 tallest are in different teams/total ways of forming two teams.

But could not solve further.Please help me.

Comment: Hint:  Boy #1 winds up on team A, say.  That leaves $10$ open slots on Team A and $11$ on team B.  Boy #2 has equal probability of occupying any given one of these open slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the tallest boys will be on a team that I will call team A.  The other team is team B.  Once you know that one of the tallest boys in on team A, there are 10 slots left on team A and 11 on team B.  So the chance that the other of the tallest boys will be on team B = 11/(10+11)=11/21

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let the tallest boy randomly select his $10$ team mates.

What is the probability the tallest of the $21$ boys will not be selected?